# Serialize JSON property name with comma in its name?

Tags: c#

I am trying to retrieve JSON data from an API, but one of the property names comes as `@data.context` . It is not a nested property. I've tested it with ExpandoObject as well, it is exactly like that. Normally in C # I would make a data model like

```
public class Data
{
  public string @odata.context { get ; set; }
}
```

But this doesn't work, as C# doesn't let me have a comma in the variable name, nor have quotes around it. The `@` sign is already there

The JSON is as follows: this property that contains a link and then another one that contains a list of objects.

```
{
 "@odata.context": "some link here",
  "list" [ {}, {}
 ]
}
```

The list of objects do not give me any trouble, only the first property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JsonPropertyName attribute to map the json to the property e.g:

```
[JsonPropertyName("@odata.context")] 
public string DataContext { get ; set; }
```

[Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties)

Comment: @crystyxn This presumes that you're using System.Text.Json to do your JSON deserialization. Other libraries may have different attributes to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You might be consuming a poorly designed API. There are API specifications that tells how to structure and name JSON keys.
One way you can accomplish is

1 Fetch JSON response from API

2 Replace "@data.context" with "Context" or something similar in JSON string

3 Create class with property

```
public class Data
{
  public string Context { get ; set; }
}
```

4 Deserialise it

Comment: I think this is the best one. Just make a replacement in the string